# How to add new product problem solve(There has been an error processing your request) in magento?

Tags: magento1.9.2.4

"catalog > manage new product > add product > continue" then...
[image]

after...
"domain > public_html > magento > error"
local.xml.sample change rename local.xml
"domain > public_html > magento > lib > zend > cache > backend > file.php"
edit code row no 99 'null' to 'tmp/'
"domain > public_html > magento" create new folder tmp
then reload further this problem
[image]

How can solve please help me

Answer (score 0):

It's seems error is for source model of attribute. May be you have used some module for productslider which creat attribute `is_feature` and now it's remove or not getting that model. So solutions here will be.

Remove `is_feature` from `eav_attribute` table  or just change source model from same table.